# CanBus. CanMessage. Формат сообщения

Tags: java, android, usb, can

Помогите, пожалуйста, начинающему разработчику. Хочу прочитать некоторую диагностическую информацию с ЭБУ автомобиля. Использую смартфон с поддержкой OTG и USB->OBDII кабель на чипе FTDI FT232RL (**не ELM327**). Не могу разобраться в формате отправляемой посылки - в разных источниках описываются разные дополнительные данные, которые следует отправить. Я отправляю посылку в таком формате (на примере запроса температуры охлаждающей жидкости):

```
    0x07 0xDF 0x02 0x01 0x05 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
```

где:
0x7DF - ID запроса
0x02 - количество байт полезной нагрузки
0x01 - запрашиваемый сервис
0x05 - запрашиваемый параметр
Но в ответ я получаю не то, что ожидаю и не то, что описано в разных открытых источниках. Скорее всего я упускаю какой-то дополнительный важный параметр, но, к сожалению, уже очень долго не могу понять какой.

Использую библиотеку [felHR85](https://github.com/felHR85/UsbSerial).

Так же могу предположить, что указываю неправильный Baudrate, но даже тупым ручным перебором я не добился правильного ответа от ЭБУ.

Буду благодарен за любую информацию!